# How to stop Wizard Redirecting to Next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

i am using wizard [two pane form] for data `crud` operation using `ajax` and `asp.net`.

Problem is : **How to stop wizard moving to next page on success?**

Explanation:

> when i press `save` button given in wizard, when all data is stored into database it shows the `success response` on `next page`. which is not good in my case. I want to show the response using `alert` but it moves to next page to show the `ajax response` message.

Save button CODE :

```html
<button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn bg-teal-400 stepy-finish">Save <i class="icon-check position-right"></i></button>
```

Ajax Save Request Code:

```html
            $("#dialogForm").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {

                var form = $('#frmCashPaymentVoucher');
                var url = form.attr('action');
                var formData = form.serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (data) {

                        $('#dialogForm').html(data);
                        $('#modal_backdrop').modal('show');
                        //alert(data);
                    },
                    cache: false

                });

            });
```

Please Help me Out ..

Comment: can you share the wizard code?

Comment: `wizard ` is plugin type i.e this was added into the template of project and then what you supposed to be share for wizard ?

Answer (score -1):

Use This Code

$("#dialogForm").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {

```
        debugger;


            form = $('#frmCashPaymentVoucher');
            var url = form.attr('action');
            var formData = form.serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {

                    $('#dialogForm').html(data);
                    $('#modal_backdrop').modal('show');
                    //alert(data);

                },
                error: function(err) {
                    alert("Failed to load ...!!!");
                }
            });


        });
```